# Monaco editor deltaDecorations changes the style of the whole text instead of just the given range

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I am using Monaco editor with [React](https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor). I want to change the background color of a specific range in a line. I am following [this tutorial](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#interacting-with-the-editor-line-and-inline-decorations) which is from the official documentation.

Here's how the code looks like.

```js
const editorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    const r = new monaco.Range(1, 3, 1, 10);
    editor.deltaDecorations(
        [],
        [
            {
                range: r,
                options: {
                    inlineClassName: "myInlineDecoration",
                },
            },
        ]
    );
};
```

This is how I create the editor element. Nothing special.

```js
<MonacoEditor
    width={800}
    height={400}
    language="java"
    value={value}
    onChange={onValueChange}
    editorDidMount={editorDidMount}
/>
```

and the css

```css
.myInlineDecoration {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

The problem is that this changes the background color of the whole text to `lightgreen` instead of just the given range.

It looks like this. But I just want a specific range, not everything.
[image]

I tried different options from [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodeldecorationoptions.html) but none of them made any difference.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: I forked the react-monaco-editor repo and copied/pasted your code in the example and it works https://github.com/diedu89/react-monaco-editor could you check you are using the latest version available? it would really help if you try to reproduce the bug in the repo example as well

Comment: I checked your code, it did not necessarily work for me, but it kind of gave me an idea about what can go wrong. So, the problem was, my initial value for the editor was an empty string, and in the editorDidMount I set the range and all that. This got applied to an empty string, but when I changed it, it got applied to the whole thing,It was not refreshed. If you pay attention, in the monaco editor if you start writing at the end of the range, the coloring gets applied to the new area as well. That was the problem. I just saved the editor as a state, and then used it whenever necessary.Thanks!

Comment: got it. If you found a solution, please post an answer with the details and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, the problem seems to be that the value starts as blank, and then the selection auto-expands to the whole text when it changes.

If you want to keep decorations when the text changes, you could store the monaco objects in a ref and use them in a `useEffect` hook that executes every time the value changes.

```
...
  const monacoObjects = useRef(null);

  const editorDidMount = (editor, monaco) => {
    monacoObjects.current = {
      editor,
      monaco,
    };
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!monacoObjects.current) return;
    const { monaco, editor } = monacoObjects.current;
    const r = new monaco.Range(1, 3, 1, 10);
    editor.deltaDecorations(
      [],
      [
        {
          range: r,
          options: {
            inlineClassName: "myInlineDecoration",
          },
        },
      ]
    );
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <MonacoEditor
      width={800}
      height={400}
      language="java"
      value={value}
      onChange={onValueChange}
      editorDidMount={editorDidMount}
    />
  );
...
```